# Cannot SSH into EC2 instance because public DNS name is blank

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, dns

I'm trying to SSH into an EC2 instance using a command like this:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/mykey.pem ubuntu@<ec2_public_DNS_name>
```

But, the PublicDnsName field is showing up blank on the command line after I create the instance. I have already tried to set DNS Hostnames to yes in the VPC dashboard (and then terminated and created another instance). I have also checked the subnet and Auto-Assign public IP is set to yes.

Where can I find the public DNS name?

Comment: instead of dns, if you have a public ip then you that.

Comment: step 1: did you succeed in getting into the instance via the ssh given you in the "Connect" tab?

Comment: When you enable Auto-Assign public IP, you never get a public DNS name. You get a public IP only. If you need public DNS, you need to create an EIP and associate it to your EC2 instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you've described, your instance has probably been stopped.  If you're using [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), you can query your instance details including its public DNS hostname if you know your `instance ID`:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-XXXXXXXX
```

Or, if you only know the `AMI ID` your instance was created from:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=image-id,Values=ami-XXXXXXXX"
```

You should also be able to review all instances owned by your AWS account by visiting [AWS EC2 dashboard](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/home) from a browser.